# Apply only one class to tinymce element

Tags: css, tinymce

Here is my custom format:

```
style_formats: [
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
],
```

with
 `content_css: "style.css",`

so that I able to see the instant changes of my content.

and the css for both classes:

```
.example1
{
color:blue;
}
.example2
{
color:yellow;
}
```

I noticed if I changed my class from `example1` to `example2`,the source code becomes:

`<span class="example1 example2">Do you know?</span>`

Is there anyway to only apply one class to an element? Or am I need to highlight the same span,reselect the class to remove it,and select another new class everytime?

I'm using the newest version 4.0.25.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640053/tinymce-stacks-classes