# TinyMCE stacks classes

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE 4 as my default editor. In the config I specified style formats. This works excuistly except for one thing: it stacks classes.

My style format:

```
style_formats: [
        { title: 'Heading 2', block: 'h2', classes: 'heading-02' },
        { title: 'Heading 3', block: 'h3', classes: 'heading-03' },
        { title: 'Heading 4', block: 'h4', classes: 'heading-04' },
        { title: 'Heading 5', block: 'h5', classes: 'heading-05' },
        { title: 'Text', block: 'p', classes: 'copy-02' },
    ],
```

After selecting text and switching between format, the end result looks like this:

```
<h4 class="heading-02 heading-03 heading-04">example</h4>
```

Obviously there should be no other classes than heading-04 alone. But non the less it adds them anyways.

My question therefore is, how can I make sure there is only 1 class after a format switch.

Comment: Can you try with the latest TinyMCE version?

Comment: I am, cdn: //cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js

Comment: I'd love to hear an anwser to this. That being said, I have a workaround. In my particular case the heading-02 has a fallback, namely h2. So in my case I will just remove classes in all and just use block level elements which switch fine. But I can most def see a scenario in which this does matter.

Answer (score -1):

Add style_formats_merge: true

**style_formats_merge**

This option allows you to set whether TinyMCE should append the styles in the style_formats setting to the default style formats or completely replace them.

[Source](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#style_formats_merge)

Comment: Nope, that is just a merge between default styles and format styles. But for argument sake I have tried it, and it's not doing what I need.